# Not receiving mails php mail outlook

Tags: php, email, outlook

I have a problem with the dynamic sending of emails from my site
Customers who have hotmail, live emails do not receive emails (which are in bcc receive emails) as well as some customers with gmail for example receive them but in spam and others in main. The code I use

```
function emailDemande($email, $nameL){
if (!preg_match("#^[a-z0-9._-]+@(hotmail|live|msn).[a-z]{2,4}$#", $email))
{
    $passage_ligne = "\r\n";
}
else
{
    $passage_ligne = "\n";
}


$subject = 'Votre demande d\'expérience mystère';

$headers = "From: site <contact@site.com>".$passage_ligne;
$headers .= "Bcc: compte@gmail.com".$passage_ligne;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$passage_ligne;
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8".$passage_ligne;
$message = '<html><body><p>Cher(e) '.$nameL.',</p></body></html>';mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);};
```

Comment: And your question is what?

Comment: My question is why did not I receive the mails on hotmail and live?
Is there a problem with my code?  where is it and how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Cpanel hosting.

What you want to do is.

Go to Cpanel > MX entry > Select Domain name in question > Select Remote Mail Exchanger.

Thats it.

Comment: A wild guess, but worth a try.

Comment: Its not a wild guess, if you are indeed using Cpanel that is the culprit. I have dealt with it about 100 times.

Comment: My apologizes @arkascha I thought you were the OP. Sadly it is an ongoing issue that plagues CPanel and MS.

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with `CPanel`. It is a basic step in setting up a domain for sending and receiving email messages. In my eyes it would have made sense to _ask_ the OP first if reverse lookups work. So to post a comment. Simply since you do not know if this is the issue. That is why I called it a _guess_.

Comment: I understand. My simple reasoning was that I have experience with many servers and control panels and whenever it has been an issue with outlook or live (ms) then it has always pointed to the remote mail exchanger being the issue.

Comment: @norcaljohnny I have a V1 for my site and the emails worked correctly, my problem is with V2 despite that I kept the same MX mail
(yes   i am using Cpanel OVH)

Comment: @lolla sadly the only problem is with Cpanel. I have encountered it only when Cpanel is used and nothing else was ever changed. Give it a go and test it.